# Mysql - Cannot add foreign key constraint, there is no forign key in SQL query

Tags: mysql

This question is completely different from similar ones. There is no foreign key in the SQL query. This is a silly error I see when I import the SQL file on remote server. This is the SQL code

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

As you see there is no foreign key, But when I run the following code, it is ok

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ;
```

If I rename it to something else it is OK too.

```
CREATE TABLE `locationssss` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Is this the whole error? `Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: Yes. It is just this!!

Comment: Do you have more tables within your database? If so, is there a table that does contain a foreign key connected with the `locations` table?

Comment: @YoramdeLangen yes you are right. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just for future references:**

Do you have more tables within your database? If so, is there a table that does contain a foreign key connected with the `locations` table?